# PHP display problem

Tags: php

How can I refresh a page and have the user data display in the text field the same way it was entered using PHP for example, Example 1 should display the same when refreshed and not look like Example 2.

Example 1

```
&amp;amp;
```

Example 2

```
&amp;
```

Comment: Have you started writing some code? Does it need to remember the values of the code without the form being submitted?

Comment: I already echo the data using POST

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to render your text. This will escape all special chars so that browsers render the text correctly.

Alternately, you could use enclose your text within [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) or [`<pre`>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tags.

Comment: In the world of web pages, `CDATA` markers are effective only in true XHTML (i.e. with a content type of `application/xhtml+xml`) which isn't supported by Internet Explorer 8 and lower. `<pre>` will not work, it says that white space is significant, not that other markup should be ignored. And W3Schools is a dreadful reference, don't go near it.

Comment: `htmlentities` will work, but will make unnecessary additional changes.

Comment: @David Dorward what kind of changes?

Comment: It'll splat anything non-ASCII into multiple bytes.

Comment: @David Dorward can u give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to display *text* in an HTML document generated by PHP, use the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function to convert characters that have special meaning to their respective entities.